# Putting a button or text on an exact place of a scrollable background image

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

Say I have a background image as such.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkbeg.png

I want to put a button or text right inside the white box. My text or button must scale and fit the box perfectly when the image is scaled according to device screen size. The image does not fit the screen vertically so it is scrollable. I know that I need to put them in a group if I want them both to scroll together.

But how do I place the button inside the box? Since its scrollable I dont know the exact x and y values of the box. Not to mention these values will change according to device screen size. And how do I make the buttons scale to fit the box with all screen sizes?

This image is only an example. Of course I wouldn't have a problem if I drew the box myself programmatically. I would know where to put the button. Assume I dont know the coordinates and the size of the box since I didn't d

Answer (score 0):

If your box object is called `box`, set the button to the `box.x` and `box.y` like this:

```
object1.x = box.x
object1.y = box.y
```

Comment: I dont know what box.x and box.y is. I didnt draw it. It comes with the background image.

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't realize that was an actually picture. Well if it's the background, just measure how many pixels the box is away from the left edge in photoshop, and then just set the object to that x and y in corona.

Answer (score 0):

The scroll aspect should not matter if you put the button and image in same group and scroll the group. Then all you need to do is position the button relative to the image once, the rest will be taken care of by corona.

What will matter is the screen resolution. One way of tackling this is to view the image at full resolution and compute at what x and y pixels the box is located. For instance,

```
image: 200 x 300 pixels
box top left: 100, 100 (pixels from top left of image)
box width height: 20, 60
```

Then you use ratios: top left of button box is at 0.5, 0.3333 of image size; the button box width is 0.1 and height 0.2 of image size. Then when you start app, you compute what will be the image scaling factor based on actual resolution and you apply that to box coordinates:

```
device 300 x 400: 
    image will be scaled 1.5x in width, 1.333x in height
    so button box should be at (200*1.5*0.5, 300*1.333*0.333) 
    with width 20*1.5 and height 60*1.333
```